# Installing Ubuntu in Google Nexus 7 Tablet

Tags: 13.04, nexus-7

i would like to install Ubuntu in my new Nexus-7 Tab, can you please help me with complete installation procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this procedure to install Ubuntu Touch on your Nexus 7 tablet:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

**Note**: only the **Nexus 7 2013 WiFi** (codename **flo**) is supported.